# Convert CSV entries into list of tuples without changing data types

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV entry is as follows:

```
1500, 'data', '10.10.10.1', 2.0, 1
1501, 'header', '10.10.10.14', 2.1, 0
...
```

I want to load it into my program this way:

```
[(1500, 'data', '10.10.10.1', 2.0, 1), (1501, 'header', '10.10.10.14', 2.1, 0), ...]
```

I am trying to do this for millions of records, so splitting each row and converting to desired datatype seems tedious.

Any advice?

I tried with csv library, but that just converts the whole thing into a string. Pandas also did not load it as a tuple.

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

The CSV library is not doing any conversion, the file is a string. It is up to the script to convert each value as required. For example:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r", newline="") as f_in:
    csv_in = csv.reader(f_in, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)  # Single quote rather than default double quote
    data = [(int(row[0]), *row[1:3], float(row[3]), int(row[4])) for row in csv_in]

    print(data)
```

This would display your tuples as follows:

```
[(1500, 'data', '10.10.10.1', 2.0, 1), (1501, 'header', '10.10.10.14', 2.1, 0)]
```